# AngularJS Date filter using momentjs returns more values than required

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I'm importing data from Laravel through a GET request by angularJS. The result:

```
"vacations":[
    {
        "id":1,
        "timeschedule_id":1,
        "begindate":"2017-04-28 00:00:00",
        "enddate":"2017-04-30 00:00:00",
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "timeschedule_id":1,
        "begindate":"2017-05-05 00:00:00",
        "enddate":"2017-05-06 00:00:00",
    }
]
```

*Note that this vacations JSON Array is inside **data** JSON Array*

---

Now I have made the following filter to check if the date from getDate() is between the begindate and the enddate in my controller:

```
$scope.vacation = data.data[0].vacations.filter(function (d) {
    if(moment(d.begindate).format("DD-MM-YYYY") <= $scope.getDate(4) 
       && $scope.getDate(4) <= moment(d.enddate).format("DD-MM-YYYY")) {
         return true;
    }
});
```

---

The getDate() Function is a simple function and nothing more than this:

```
$scope.getDate = function($days_forward) {
     return moment().add($days_forward + $scope.i, 'days').format("DD-MM-YYYY");
};
```

---

This filter returns the correct results but also more results than required. For example this line is also coming through but it shouldn't:

```
28-05-2017 // Result from getDate()
```

How do I make sure that only dates between `2017-04-28 00:00:00` - `2017-04-30 00:00:00`and `2017-05-05 00:00:00` - `2017-05-06 00:00:00` are returned from my filter?

Comment: Use moment [query](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/) functions like `isSame`, `isAfter` and `isBefore` to compare moment objects instead of formatting them to strings and comparing via `<=`

Comment: @VincenzoC I was indeed comparing a string to a momentjs object. I will post the answer below.

Comment: I posted an answer the shoes how you can use [`isBetween`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/) method, it combines `isAfter` and `isBetween`.

Comment: @VincenzoC Thanks. I posted my answer also below but it was indeed the same thing I was looking for so you can take the credit.

Comment: Perfect, I'm happy you resolved your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`isBetween`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/). Your code could be like the following:

```
$scope.vacation = data.data[0].vacations.filter(function (d) {
    if( $scope.getDate(4).isBetween(d.begindate, d.enddate) ) {
        return true;
    }
});

$scope.getDate = function($days_forward) {
    return moment().startOf('day').add($days_forward + $scope.i, 'days');
}
```

The `getDate` function now returns a moment object instead of a string.

If you need you can customize inclusivity:

> Version **2.13.0** introduces inclusivity. A `[` indicates inclusion of a value. A `(` indicates exclusion. If the inclusivity parameter is used, both indicators must be passed.
>
> If the inclusivity parameter is not specified, Moment will default to `()`.

---

As a general rule, as stated in the comments, use moment [query](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/) functions like `isSame`, `isAfter`, `isBefore` etc to compare moment objects instead of formatting them to strings and comparing via `<=`

Answer (score 1):

I was comparing a string to a momentJS Object so the following steps I implemented to resolve this problem:

**Changed the filter to:**

```
if($scope.getMomentDate(4).isBetween(moment(d.begindate), moment(d.enddate), 
   'days', '[]')) {  // [] = all inclusive
    return true;
}
```

**Made a helper function getMomentDate() instead of getDate()**

```
$scope.getMomentDate = function($days_forward){
    return moment().add($days_forward + $scope.i, 'days');
};
```

The **isBetween** method can be used to compare two MomentJS Objects. With the optional fourth parameter of this method i'm able to include every MomentJS Object in the given range.